# How to adjust text field reactivity in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a simple text field in Vue.js:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'Test'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="value" ref="input" />
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to decrease the frequency of updating the value in the data model from 'onChange' to 'onBlur'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

v-model is just syntax sugar for =>

**:value="modelValue" @input="modelValue = $event.target.value"**

If you want something else, it's very easy to do. Just change the update side to onBlur, so =>

```
<input  class="form-control
    :value="value" 
    @blur="value = $event.target.value"
    @input="value = $event.target.value"
>
```

The improved example code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'Test'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
    type="text"
    :value="value"
    @blur="value = $event.target.value"
    ref="input"
    />
  <p>{{ value }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should Just add `@blur` event, and pass through it the value of the event

Then when this event gets triggered in `methods`, it will change the value of `result` to the input value...so the updating became only conditioned to `blur` of the input

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result: '',
    value:''
  },
  methods:{
   blo(e){
     this.result = e
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @blur='blo(value)' v-model="value" />
  <p>{{ result }}</p>
</div>
</div>
```